# Tag wiki for [php] is out of date, or Should tag wikis include "current" version numbers?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Super User has a [php](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/php) tag.  (There is also a  [php5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/php5) tag, which is much less used and maybe not necessary)

I was a little surprised at first when I saw it, since it's a programming language.  It does seem to attract some off-topic questions, but that's not what my question is about.  When I looked at the tag wiki, I noticed the excerpt says:

> The current version is 5.3.3, released on July 22, 2010.

PHP isn't on hiatus or anything, there have been plenty of new versions since 2010.  According to [php.net](http://php.net), the current version is 5.6.12, and PHP 7 is in its third beta.

I was going to edit it but then I realized that if I just update the version number, it will have to be changed again soon.  I don't spend as much time here on Super User as I do on Stack Overflow, so I'm not sure what the consensus on version numbers in tag wikis is around here, and I couldn't find anything in the help center or on meta.

Should the version number simply be updated?

> The current version is 5.6.12, released on August 6, 2015.

That will need to be updated every month when a new bugfix update comes out.

Should it be changed to include just the major version number?

> The current major version is PHP 5.

That's practically meaningless because PHP 5 came out a long time ago and each "minor" version number since then has included significant changes.

Should it be changed to include the major and minor version number?

> The current version is PHP 5.6.x.

That will need to be updated less often, but it will still need to be updated soon when PHP 7 comes out.

Should it mention PHP 7?

> The current version is PHP 5.6.x, and PHP 7 is currently in beta.

or

> The current PHP 5 version is 5.6.x, and the current PHP 7 version is Beta 3.

Or should it not mention the version at all?  That leaves the wiki excerpt as just one sentence, but maybe that's OK.

**Edit:** The [Stack Overflow equivalent of this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) does not mention the version number, for what it's worth.

Comment: Why not just add a link to Wikipedia?

Comment: @Pacerier For that matter, why not a link to php.net?  I don't know what the usual practice with respect to external links is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think version numbers are helpful in any shape or form in our tag wiki.

If someone wants to know what the latest version of a software is, the Super User tag wiki is not the right place to learn it.

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well.  I submitted a suggested edit that just removes the version info, although maybe the wiki can still be improved in other ways.

Comment: Versions are needed tho for some software types. Say Microsoft Excel. There is a big different between 2007 to 2013.

Comment: @MrStatic However, there we have `microsoft-excel-2007` and `microsoft-excel-2013` tags.

Comment: @MrStatic: The major version of certain software products can be relevant. Which is why they are included in the tag itself (as Michael pointed out). The question is about the tag *wiki*, which has far lower visibility.

Comment: @MrStatic Right, I'm not questioning the value of having different tags to distinguish between major versions.  When PHP 7 comes out, maybe it'll make sense to have a [php5] and a [php7], although since the differences between PHP versions are usually differences in the language itself, that distinction might not matter for Super User's purposes.  Like I said, though, in this specific case, saying "PHP 5" doesn't mean much since PHP 5.6 has seen lots of changes since 5.0.